# Como fazer uma contagem regressiva com jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Estou fazendo um script para fins de estudo [**nesse link**](http://axitech.com.br/ccl/) e gostaria de implementar nesse script um relógio com contagem regressiva como se faz em sites de compra coletiva e gostaria da ajuda de vocês para realizar esta tarefa.

O que eu já fiz foi cadastrar no banco de dados o horário de ***começo*** e de ***fim*** em cada um dos produtos e gostaria de realizar este contador regressivo. Também já puxei as informações do banco para a view como pode ser visto.

Outra coisa que fiz foi converter para ***timestamp começo*** e ***fim***.

O formato da data no banco de dados esta em ***DATETIME***.

***Pergunta***: este é o formato certo de campo para realizar a subtração do tempo mostrando assim o tempo restante ou eu devo converter esse formato antes de realizar a operação de subtração?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem alguns plugins já prontos que é possível fazer isso sem muita dor de cabeça, seguem dois exemplos:

1 - [FlipClock](http://flipclockjs.com/) (já com css):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="flipclock.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="flipclock.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="clock" style="margin:2em;"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var clock;

                clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
                    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
                    autoStart: false,
                    callbacks: {
                        stop: function() {
                            alert('Fim!')
                        }
                    }
                });

                clock.setTime(3600); // tempo em segundos
                clock.setCountdown(true);
                clock.start();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

2 - [jQuery.countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/) (mais básico pra trabalhar da forma como quiser e com opção de formato de data):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.countdown.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id="clock"></span>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#clock').countdown('2015/10/09 12:34:56', function(event) {
                    $(this).html(event.strftime('%D dias %H:%M:%S'));
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

São apenas 2 dos diversos plugins disponíveis para sua aplicação, basta escolher o que melhor se adéqua. Referente ao formato, como mostrado cada um trabalha de uma forma, tem que converter conforme o plugin que for utilizar.

Espero que ajude, abraço

Answer (score -2):

```
// jQuery, nesse exemplo remove a class 'hide' do btn depois de 10 seg.
        let contador = 10;
        contadorMenos = setInterval(() => {
          if( contador <= 0){
            $('#relogio').html('');
            $('#btnatualizar').removeClass('hide');
          }else{
            $('#relogio').html(contador + 's , aguarde...');
          }
          contador--;
        }, 1000);
```